# How to get property from a nullable type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get the price total from an instance of a type that is in another table using `virtual` but the catch is that the instance can be null and whenever it is null it throws an exception. Is there any way to allow the type to be null and still get a return on the property?

```cs
// Trying to get product price from products table, throws exception when Product is null
            {order.Product.PriceTotal}
```

Whenever product is null it throws an exception.

Comment: No, if the product is null then how can you even have a price on that product? Makes no sense to get a price on a product that doesn't exist. You need to perform a check on the Product to see if it is null or not. If it is not null, then you can get the price. Otherwise you don't get price.

Comment: I want to test multiple times where Product can be either populated or null.

Comment: Then do an initial check to see if order.Product is null.  If product is not null, then get the price using order.Product.PriceTotal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is add the null propagation operator `?` after the type.

```cs
// Trying to get product price from products table, throws exception when Product is null
            {order.Product?.PriceTotal}
```

This will mean that if `Product` is null, it will set the `PriceTotal` as null